# Matching objects from two separate arrays based on a key value

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays. One is filled with objects of customer information and the other is objects of insurance claims.

```
customer = [{"Last Name":"lastname", "First Name":"firstname", "ID":"6583142"}]

claim = [{"ID"=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"}]
```

The goal is to match each claim to a customer. I understand how to see if an ID from one exists in the other, but how would I associate the two? I don't believe putting the matched claims somewhere else makes sense because in the next part each claim needs to be accepted or declined whether they are matched or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Could you put an example with input / output?

Comment: Sorry, that's all the instruction I was given. Match the claims data to the appropriate customer. Each array has more than one customer/claim. I used 1 for each in the example just to show a claim that should be matched to a customer.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is a *pseudo database like search*.

I'm using plural for collections:

```
customers = [{"Last Name": "lastname", "First Name": "firstname", "ID": "6583142"}]
claims = [{"ID"=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"}]
```

Claim has one customer, so first look for the claim by claim number, then look for its customer:

```
claim_number = "123214"
claim = claims.detect { |h| h["number"] == claim_number }
customer = customers.detect { |h| h[:"ID"] == claim["ID"] }
#=> {:"Last Name"=>"lastname", :"First Name"=>"firstname", :ID=>"6583142"}
```

Customer has many claims, so, given the customer id, find all claims:

```
customer_id = "6583142"
p all_claim_by_customer = claims.select { |h| h["ID"] == customer_id }
#=> [{"ID"=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"}]
```

I suggest to use symbols as keys for hashes.

Comment: Good point about the possibility of one customer having multiple claims.

Answer (score 1):

```
customers = [{ "Last Name":"Hardplace",  "First Name":"Rockina", "ID":"6583142" },
             { "Last Name":"Bebblebrox", "First Name":"Zaphod",  "ID":"6583143" }]

claims =    [{ "ID"=>"6583143", "number"=>"123215", "start_date"=>"2018-10-04" },
             { "ID"=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03" }]

def by_id(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:ID]] = g }
end

customers_by_id = by_id(customers)
  #=> {"6583142"=>{:"Last Name"=>"Hardplace", :"First Name"=>"Rockina", :ID=>"6583142"},
  #    "6583143"=>{:"Last Name"=>"Bebblebrox", :"First Name"=>"Zaphod", :ID=>"6583143"}}
adj_claims = claims.map { |h| h.transform_keys { |k| k == "ID" ? :ID : k } }
  #=> [{:ID=>"6583143", "number"=>"123215", "start_date"=>"2018-10-04"},
  #    {:ID=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"}]
claims_by_id = by_id(adj_claims)
  #=> {"6583143"=>{:ID=>"6583143", "number"=>"123215", "start_date"=>"2018-10-04"},
  #    "6583142"=>{:ID=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"}}
```

Given a claim id, say `"6583142"`, the customer and claims information are contained in the  hashes:

```
customers_by_id["6583142"]
  #=> {:"Last Name"=>"Hardplace", :"First Name"=>"Rockina", :ID=>"6583142"}
```

and

```
claims_by_id["6583142"]
  #=> {:ID=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"}
```

If desired, the pairs hashes having the same `ID` could be merged, but it is not really necessary.

```
customers_by_id.keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,h|
  h[k] = customers_by_id[k].merge(claims_by_id[k]) }
  #=> {"6583142"=>{:"Last Name"=>"Hardplace", :"First Name"=>"Rockina",
  #                :ID=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"},
  #    "6583143"=>{:"Last Name"=>"Bebblebrox", :"First Name"=>"Zaphod",
  #                :ID=>"6583143", "number"=>"123215", "start_date"=>"2018-10-04"}}
```

The calculation of `adj_claims` is needed because the ID is represented by a symbol in `customers` and by a string in `claims`. See [Hash#transform_keys](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys). It is a symbol in `adj_claims`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
customer = [{"Last Name" => "lastname", "First Name" => "firstname", "ID" => "6583142"}]
claim = [{"ID"=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"}]

# Get all uniq ids
ids = (claim + customer).map {|object| object['ID']}.uniq

# Find claims and customers for every id
merged_data = ids.map do |id| 
    {
        id: id, 
        claims: claim.select{|claim| claim['ID'] == id}, 
        customers: customer.select{|customer| customer['ID'] == id}
    }
end
```

result will be:

```
[{
  :id=>"6583142", 
  :claims=>[{"ID"=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03"}], 
  :customers=>[{"Last Name"=>"lastname", "First Name"=>"firstname", "ID"=>"6583142"}]
}]
```

Also, if for every ID you have only one claim and only one Customer you can just merge it:

```
ids.map do |id|
    claim_hash = claim.select{|claim| claim['ID'] == id}.first
    customer_hash = customer.select{|customer| customer['ID'] == id}.first
    claim_hash.merge customer_hash
end
[{"ID"=>"6583142", "number"=>"123214", "start_date"=>"2018-10-03", "Last Name"=>"lastname", "First Name"=>"firstname"}]
```